# JsonConvert - Ignore [PropertyName("FooBar")]?

Tags: c#, json.net

Is there a way to serialize a object ignoring the `[PropertyName("FooBar")]`?

Details: My object has enormous property names that are read all over the frontend... the problem is that it causes me to waste about 35% of space... when you take caching in consideration, this is a huge problem

Comment: Can you remove the `[PropertyName("FooBar")]` ?

Comment: @Mafii my intent is to place it, and have the serialization to the front end ignore it... serialize to cache will use it

Comment: You can probably accomplish this by creating a contract resolver, which inherits from `DefaultContractResolver`, and using that resolver in the front end where you want to ignore the attributes.

Comment: @Amy would you pls put it as answer... it's good enough for me

Comment: @Leonardo okay, I submitted it as an answer.  Should I elaborate at all (i dont mind)?  Or is it okay as-is?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by creating a contract resolver, which inherits from `DefaultContractResolver`, and using that resolver in the front end where you want to ignore the attributes.